# React using map to create components but can't use functions

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and having some problems. I want to create components depending on a JSON setstate but when I use map it doesn't seem to work.

```
var displays = this.state.name.map(function(id) {
    return (
        <MenuItems onClick={this.clicked} name={id.program}  />
    )
});
```

As soon as I set onClick the page fails to load. If I get rid of onClick the page works. I need to do something when a button is clicked so it is essential.

I am calling the function with

```
{displays}
```

in the render method and it seems to work for my other components. The state is set like this:

```
    name: [{"program": "File Manager"},
           {"program": "Add File"},
           {"program": "Index"},
           {"program": "File Editor"}],
```

How come I am unable to call functions when I use map in this way? Is my callback wrong? I have been working on this problem for a while, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map has an optional parameter to pass this.

```js
var displays = this.state.name.map(function(id) {
    return (
        <MenuItems onClick={this.clicked} name={id.program}  />
    )
}, this);
```